# i have create a basic store procedure..when i m changing in this and execute it give me error that this name of SP already exit

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my code

```
USE AccountSystemTraining
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.precetics
AS
SELECT * FROM Department where id=1
GO
```

error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure precetics, Line 4 There is
>   already an object named 'precetics' in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If the procedure already exists and you need to change it then you may need to use ALTER instead of CREATE:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.precetics AS SELECT * FROM Department where id=1 GO
```

Note: From SQL Server 2016 you can do

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.precetics AS SELECT * FROM Department where id=1 GO
```

which will always work without erroring regardless the procedure exists or not. In previous SQL server you can go around the issue by testing for existence first.

Comment: This answer is correct only if the `precetics` existing in the database is actually a stored procedure... It might be a table or view or any other database object...