# Is it possible to invoke a SQL server parameterized stored procedure in ADO.NET like in ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, odbc

For example ... in odbc this works fine ......

```
string commandText = $"exec sp_InsertStudentMaster 'X', 'Y','Z'";
var command = new OdbcCommand(commandText,cn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Just add parameters to the OdbcParameterCollection and specify "?" parameter tokens in the query string. The [reference documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx) includes an example.

Comment: I know.. in fact the above code works fine for odbc  .. but i want to call the procedure using ado.net with all the parameters in a single line beside procedure name .. just like in odbc

Comment: Not sure I understand. You should be able to execute a query with all the parameters on one line:  `string commandText = $"exec sp_InsertStudentMaster ?, ?, ?";`. You just need to add the parameters to the command object in the same order before executing the query as described in the reference.

Comment: Shouldn't command type in this case be `Text`
?

Comment: Slight detour....you should avoid using the sp_ prefix. You need to find a different prefix, or even better is no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Here is one reason why I like prefixing stuff. Read my comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028803/3094533). Also, I just had a case where I had to add a reference to a table with a column named `order`. The 3rd party tool I was using failed to do it, complaining about `incorrect syntax near keyword order`. Since this was on a production server, I had to create a view just to keep that stupid column name intact. Then I found out I can only import the view to the 3rd party tool if all views in the database where OK. They wasn't. I had to spend almost an hour deleting old views

Comment: Just because the current naming standards in the company I work for demands no prefixes in column name, and someone was dumb enough to call the column `order` instead of `ordinal`. Back in the day, I had all column name prefixed with the table name or an abbreviation of it, thus eliminating the chance of such a problem to exists in the first place. (both comments addressed to @SeanLange)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I see your point but the problem in your case and the other one is that the names of the objects are total crap. They are incredibly generic which is a very bad thing for a name of an object. Seriously, a column named order. That deserves a slap in the back of the head to the idiot that used that name. In that example a prefix is dealing with the symptom, not the cause. Joe Celko uses the term "tibbling" to refer to prefixing names. Came from the tblSomething style which is an odd throwback to VB6. I didn't like it then either because changing types was difficult.

Comment: I tootlay plan to do it.... @sean